# What is the difference between withRouter() HOC and when to use useHistory() hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I have been constantly try to understand what is the difference between withRouter() HOC and useHistory() hooks.

Meanwhile i am seeing both can able to access the history ,location, and match props even it outside the the component which is not directly mounted through Route component.

Comment: Do you have some examples?

Comment: You will find the best answer from the doc, https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory